# Синтаксический разбор 2-х предложений

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Неделю назад наступила весна.
Все дети вышли гулять на улицу.

Comment: 105.228 раз сказано: ДЗ не выполняются.

Comment: @Almaznik105.228 1. Дайте свое решение (или хотя бы мнение). Если что-то будет _не так_, Вам обязательно укажут на ошибки. 2. Количественное числительное **двух** не нуждается в наращении.

Answer (score 1):

1) Неделю назад наступила весна.
Весна - что? - подлежащее.
Наступила - весна что сделала? - сказуемое.
Неделю назад - наступила когда? - обстоятельство.

2) Все дети вышли гулять на улицу.
Все дети - кто? - подлежащее.
Вышли гулять - все дети что сделали? - сказуемое.
На улицу - вышли гулять куда? - обстоятельство.